# Figure out possible ways to save mp4 streamed from internet

Tags: save, video-streaming, mp4

**Summary:**
While a video is streaming in the internet browser, packets of mp4 files are being downloaded.

I would like to write some code that saves the packets into one file so the video is preserved after it is done streaming.

I think this could be done by taking the packets in as byte files, removing how ever many bytes the addressing header at the front is made out of, and then concatenating the rest, but I will be the first to admit that I have never done anything like this before and don't really know what I am doing.

If anyone out there has experience with with this kind of thing, I am not looking for much, just a few words to point me in the right direction, or at least keep me from going too far in the wrong direction. I am really just coming at this project with half a CS degree and some notions about what to google right now.

Specific Questions:

1. Do you know how I can access the data packs being downloaded from the internet? For example, if I wanted to make a script that grabbed each of the mp4 data packs as they came in, what kind of command would I use to access them?
2. Do you know what would be the best way to save the video file? Should I access the data packs as they come in? or should I access them later, as they have been strung together by the media player? Is the second part even possible or would the data be protected by that time?
3. If you don't have answers to these questions, are you able to give me a reference to a place the does? I haven't been able to find this subject on stack. Even some good keywords to search for would be useful.

Thanks for taking the time to read,
-Coder 357

TLDR: Trying to make code or script to save the mp4 packets into video files as they are streamed.

**Progress So Far:**
I suppose all I have done is press f12 and open up the network activity section of the internet page, streaming the video I want to capture. I know that I am rapidly fetching mp4 files in the kb and mb size range. That is what lead me to my conclusion that I will likely need to string these mp4 files together into one file, after removing any extra bits and bytes at the front and end.

That being said, I don't have an understanding of how my media player holds the data, so there may be a much more convenient way to do this that I am not seeing.

**Goal:**
My best case expectation for the project is to have a program or script which can be run from the command line and will then combined mp4 data packets, from a given website, into a single video file.

Comment: does the stream use a standard dash manifest (mpd), If so, you can just ffmpeg to download and combine in one step

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really know enough about ffmpeg to dive in, but once I did, it really did the trick :)